# matlab quiver3 plot color gradient in z direction?

Tags: matlab

so this is the quiver3 plot I got:

[image]

I would like to change the color of the arrows to be able to better distinguish the direction they are pointing in. 
I would like to have a color gradient in z direction (for example: for negative values blue, around 0 green, positive ones yellow or something like that).

Comment: Your post is not complete. Some ressources (like images) are missing. Please reformat it.

Comment: @McNight. Users with low rep can't format images as images on SO. They can only post links. That being said, I don't see a single line of code in a post asking us to modify code, so I'm  voting to close.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, I'm considering it too.

Comment: With the duplicated answer you can see how to change the color according to criteria X. They use magnitude, but you can change that to be whatever you want